More iterations of Deep Q Learning yields worse results
As a learning exercise, I am trying to implement Q-Learning and Deep Q-learning for the two player game Dots and Boxes. I have implemented Q-Learning, and it is working great. I have one model that plays itself many times. The more games it plays during training, the better it becomes at playing as both player 1 (the one who starts) and player 2. However, when I do the analogous thing for DQL, the model gets worse the more it plays. In particular, after training, when the model plays against a player that chooses actions randomly, it has a certain win-loss-tie record. The more I had trained the model, the worse this record becomes. Through various posts on this site and elsewhere, I do not necessarily expect this self-play algorithm to yield a model that plays optimally, but I was hoping it at least improved as it learned!
For the life of me, I have been unable to find any errors in my implementation, but of course I assume they are there. Or, is this outcome what I should be expecting?
The code for playing the game many times and creating a memory that stores actions and rewards is very similar to my QL code, which works well. The new part is the optimization, and then every 20 games I copy the policy network to the target network.
Below is a sketch of the (presumably flawed) DQL optimization.
current_q_values, target_q_values = [], []
policy.train()  # policy and target are subclasses of torch.nn.Module

for (
    state, # tensor representing a state
    turn, # the player who performed the action
    action, # integer specifying an edge
    new_state, # tensor representing the new state after the action
    reward, # float
    new_turn, # the player who will perform the next action
    game_over, # bool
) in memory_batch:

    if game_over:
        # When the game is over, the target q value is set to the reward
        targetq = torch.FloatTensor([reward])
    elif turn == new_turn:
        # player `turn` performed an action `action` such that
        # it is still their turn
        with torch.no_grad():
            targetq = torch.FloatTensor(
                reward
                + discount * target(new_state).max()
            )
    else:
        # player `turn` performed an action `action` such that
        # it is now the other player's turn
        with torch.no_grad():
            targetq = torch.FloatTensor(
                reward
                - discount * target(flip_state(new_state)).max()
                # flip_state makes it so that the state is now in
                # the perspective of player `new_turn`
            )

    # current Q values
    current_q_values.append(policy(state))

    # Get the target set of Q values
    target_q_value = target(state)
    target_q_value[action] = targetq
    target_q_values.append(target_q_value)

# Loss for the whole batch. loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss()
loss = loss_fn(torch.stack(current_q_list), torch.stack(target_q_list))

# Optimize the model
optimizer.zero_grad()
loss.backward()
optimizer.step()

For reference, my Q-Learning implementation (ie the one that works well) of the Bellman equation is below.
if game_over:
    Q[(state, action)] = reward
elif new_turn == turn:
    # player `turn` performed an action `action` such that
    # it is still their turn
    Q[(state, action)] = (1 - lr) * Q[(state, action)] 
        + lr * (
            reward
            + discount * max(Q[(new_state, a)] for a in actions)
        )
else:
    # player `turn` performed an action `action` such that
    # it is now the other player's turn
    Q[(state, action)] = (1 - lr) * Q[(state, action)] + 
        lr * (
            reward
            - discount * max(Q[(flip_state(new_state), a)] for a in actions)
            # flip_state makes it so that the state is now in
            # the perspective of player `new_turn`
        )

I cannot figure out why the latter works great but the former does not. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!
